# About dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have some code, its depend org.apache.batik.*. Many jars are necessary.I tried import this im my pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.batik</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-20070705</version>
    </dependency>
```

So, That I found all jars I need have entered in project libraries.Following this.
[image]

Inside this jar that has a **lib** folder, That all jars I need are in there. 
The problem is my code seems can not find some jar they need.
[image]

I can't sure if cause is the jar that I imported has a lib folder, and I found other maven jar's structure doesn't like this.
So thank if you can help me!

**EDIT 1**
I imported this successful, this dependency's type is 'pom', so I think my
code should can find those dependency they need, but in fact, it didn't work. I don't know why.

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: have you try to clean - build the project?

Comment: What Java version are you using? If it's 10 (or later), you'll need to import a module

Comment: I can't see the images but just because a JAR contains a lib folder doesn't mean those lib JARs are automatically available on the classpath. You need to extract them using, for example, the maven dependency plugin.

Comment: @GiorgosDev I just did, but it didn't work.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox It is 8

Comment: @Michael So that means I have to import exactly all maven dependency which my code depend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artifact you are using is not directly usable in maven.

If you can use a more recent version (1.9, 1.10) of batik you can try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

If not search on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/batik

In the latter case it seems you need to add each dependency one by one

Comment: I tried this, then occured a error in my pom.xm.          "Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-all:pom:1.9 less... (⌘F1) 
Inspection info: Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems."

Comment: Never heard something like this. It seems an IDE problem. Try to build via command line. Try with `mvn -U clean install` as well

Comment: I imported a dependency which type is 'pom', and all sub-module in its pom.xml.But my code still has same error. Look at my 'EDIT1'

Comment: first of all, perhaps it is a typo, the artifactId is batik-all, but why did you add all those <module> in your pom.xml? You need only to add that dependency and nothing more.

Comment: I just added this in my pom.xml . '  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
   <artifactId>batik</artifactId>
   <version>1.10</version>
   <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
'

Answer (score 0):

1. Define dependencies for all jars you use in your source code. This usually means all jars from which you import at least one class in your source code.
2. Run `clean package` with Maven.
3. If you have errors, check if dependencies are missing.
4. If you get stuck, try a new question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I got it. But  because I import exactly all jars, I don't understand the use of that summary jar.